# Replace a string with another string within a file in Python

Tags: python, string, file, replace

You will be provided a file path for input I, a file path for output O, a string S, and a string T.

Read the contents of I, replacing each occurrence of S with T and write the resulting information to file O.

You should replace O if it already exists.

```
# Get the filepath from the command line
import sys
I= sys.argv[1] 
O= sys.argv[2] 
S= sys.argv[3]
T= sys.argv[4]

# Your code goes here

# open our file for writing
file1= open(I, 'r')
file2= open(O, 'w')

file2.replace(S, T)

file1.close()
file2.close()

file2= open('O', 'r')

print(file2)
```

Here's the error I keep getting:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "write-text-file.py", line 15, in 
    file2.replace(S, T)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Error message is pretty clear. What is your question?

Comment: I guess I am confused by it saying it has no attribute 'replace', is that telling me that is the wrong command for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: open returns a file object... not a string. Read de docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: You need to perform `.replace()` on a *string* object not on the file pointer. Hence, you need to retrieve the content from `file2` before. Hint: `read()`, `readlines()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

## Here is the code (Modified)

```
# Get the filepath from the command line
import sys
import re
I= sys.argv[1] 
O= sys.argv[2] 
S= sys.argv[3]
T= sys.argv[4]

# Your code goes here

# open our file for writing
file1= open(I, 'r')
file2= open(O, 'w')
data = file1.read()
data = data.replace(S, T)
file2.write(data)

file1.close()
file2.close()

file2= open(O, 'r')
data = file2.read()
print(data)
```

Comment: Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`file2` is a file object not a string, file object's do not have replace method

try

```
with open(I, 'r') as file1, open(O, 'w') as file2:
    for line in file1.readlines():
        line=line.replace(S,T)
        file2.write(line)
```